# Accuracy of visual distance and size perception

Tags: perception, reference-request, vision

Generally speaking it is known that human observers’ perceptions of distances in depth are generally inaccurate. I guess that the accuracy is sometimes a very large degree. To be more specific I am looking for clear information (data) on that topic for healthy persons. 
What would be the errors? 10% or more?
How the errors depends on the distance?
Any help are highly welcomed.